# extracting missing elements after comparing two data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe, element

So I have a master list of 96 elements.

```
masterlist <- list(c(paste0(rep(LETTERS[1:8], each=12), rep(1:12, 8))))
```

And I have a list of 26 data frames, where each data frames contains any or all of the elements from the master list. I called these the rowcol.list. From here, I used the following code to see which of the data frames in my list of 26 data frames are different from the master list.

```
rowcol.list[!(rowcol.list%in%masterlist)]
```

The above code returned 10 data frames from the list of 26 data frames, as shown below:

```
$p01_control.txt
 [1] "A1"  "A2"  "A3"  "A5"  "A6"  "A7"  "A8"  "A9"  "A10" "A11" "A12" "B1"  "B2"  "B3"  "B4"  "B5"  "B6"  "B7"  "B8"  "B9" 
[21] "B10" "B11" "B12" "C1"  "C2"  "C3"  "C4"  "C5"  "C6"  "C7"  "C8"  "C9"  "C10" "C11" "C12" "D1"  "D2"  "D3"  "D4"  "D5" 
[41] "D6"  "D7"  "D8"  "D9"  "D10" "D11" "D12" "E1"  "E2"  "E3"  "E4"  "E5"  "E6"  "E7"  "E8"  "E9"  "E10" "E11" "E12" "F1" 
[61] "F2"  "F3"  "F4"  "F5"  "F6"  "F7"  "F8"  "F9"  "F10" "F11" "F12" "G1"  "G2"  "G3"  "G4"  "G5"  "G6"  "G7"  "G8"  "G9" 
[81] "G10" "G11" "G12" "H1"  "H2"  "H3"  "H4"  "H5"  "H6"  "H7"  "H8"  "H9"  "H10" "H11" "H12"

$p03_control.txt
[1] "A1"  "A2"  "A3"  "A4"  "A5"  "A6"  "A7"  "A8"  "A9"  "A10" "A11" "A12" "B1"  "B2"  "B3"  "B4"  "B5"  "B6"  "B7"  "B8" 
[21] "B9"  "B10" "B11" "B12" "C1"  "C2"  "C3"  "C4"  "C5"  "C6"  "C7"  "C8"  "C9"  "C10" "C11" "C12" "D1"  "D2"  "D3"  "D4" 
[41] "D5"  "D6"  "D7"  "D8"  "D9"  "D10" "D11" "D12" "E1"  "E2"  "E3"  "E4"  "E5"  "E6"  "E7"  "E8"  "E9"  "E10" "E11" "E12" 
[61] "F1"  "F2"  "F3"  "F4"  "F5"  "F6"  "F7"  "F8"  "F9"  "F10" "F11" "F12" "G1"  "G2"  "G3"  "G4"  "G5"  "G6"  "G7"  "G9" 
[81] "G10" "G11" "G12" "H1"  "H2"  "H3"  "H4"  "H5"  "H6"  "H7"  "H8"  "H9"  "H10" "H11" "H12"

$p04_pq.txt
[1] "A1"  "A2"  "A3"  "A5"  "A6"  "A7"  "A8"  "A9"  "A10" "A11" "A12" "B1"  "B2"  "B3"  "B4"  "B5"  "B6"  "B7"  "B8"  "B9" 
[21] "B10" "B11" "B12" "C1"  "C2"  "C3"  "C4"  "C5"  "C6"  "C7"  "C8"  "C9"  "C10" "C11" "C12" "D1"  "D2"  "D3"  "D4"  "D5" 
[41] "D6"  "D7"  "D8"  "D9"  "D10" "D11" "D12" "E1"  "E2"  "E3"  "E4"  "E5"  "E6"  "E7"  "E8"  "E9"  "E10" "E11" "E12" "F1" 
[61] "F2"  "F3"  "F4"  "F5"  "F6"  "F7"  "F8"  "F9"  "F10" "F11" "F12" "G1"  "G2"  "G3"  "G4"  "G5"  "G6"  "G7"  "G8"  "G9" 
[81] "G10" "G11" "H1"  "H2"  "H3"  "H4"  "H5"  "H6"  "H7"  "H8"  "H9"  "H10" "H11" "H12"

$p07_docetaxel.txt
[1] "A1"  "A2"  "A3"  "A4"  "A5"  "A6"  "A7"  "A8"  "A9"  "A10" "A11" "A12" "B1"  "B2"  "B3"  "B4"  "B5"  "B6"  "B7"  "B8" 
[21] "B9"  "B10" "B11" "B12" "C1"  "C2"  "C3"  "C4"  "C5"  "C6"  "C7"  "C8"  "C9"  "C10" "C11" "C12" "D1"  "D2"  "D3"  "D4" 
[41] "D5"  "D6"  "D7"  "D8"  "D9"  "D10" "D11" "D12" "E1"  "E2"  "E3"  "E4"  "E5"  "E6"  "E7"  "E8"  "E9"  "E10" "E11" "E12"
[61] "F1"  "F2"  "F3"  "F4"  "F5"  "F6"  "F7"  "F8"  "F9"  "F10" "F11" "F12" "G1"  "G2"  "G3"  "G4"  "G5"  "G6"  "G7"  "G9" 
[81] "G10" "G11" "G12" "H1"  "H2"  "H3"  "H4"  "H5"  "H6"  "H7"  "H8"  "H9"  "H10" "H11" "H12"

$p08_docetaxel_b.txt
[1] "E10" "E11" "E12" "F1"  "F2"  "F3"  "F4"  "F5"  "F6"  "F7"  "F8"  "F9"  "F10" "F11" "F12" "G1"  "G2"  "G3"  "G4"  "G5" 
[21] "G6"  "G7"  "G8"  "G9"  "G10" "G11" "G12" "H1"  "H2"  "H3"  "H4"  "H5"  "H6"  "H7"  "H8"  "H9"  "H10" "H11" "H12"

$p08_docetaxel.txt
[1] "A1"  "A2"  "A3"  "A4"  "A5"  "A6"  "A7"  "A8"  "A9"  "A10" "A11" "A12" "B1"  "B2"  "B3"  "B4"  "B5"  "B6"  "B7"  "B8" 
[21] "B9"  "B10" "B11" "B12" "C1"  "C2"  "C3"  "C4"  "C5"  "C6"  "C7"  "C8"  "C9"  "C10" "C11" "C12" "D1"  "D2"  "D3"  "D4" 
[41] "D5"  "D6"  "D7"  "D8"  "D9"  "D10" "D11" "D12" "E1"  "E2"  "E3"  "E4"  "E5"  "E6"  "E7"  "E8" 

$p12_dactinomycin.txt
[1] "A1"  "A2"  "A3"  "A4"  "A5"  "A6"  "A7"  "A8"  "A9"  "A10" "A11" "A12" "B1"  "B2"  "B3"  "B4"  "B5"  "B6"  "B7"  "B8" 
[21] "B9"  "B10" "B11" "B12" "C1"  "C2"  "C3"  "C4"  "C5"  "C6"  "C7"  "C8"  "C9"  "C10" "C11" "C12" "D1"  "D2"  "D3"  "D4" 
[41] "D5"  "D6"  "D7"  "D8"  "D9"  "D10" "D11" "D12" "E1"  "E2"  "E3"  "E4"  "E5"  "E6"  "E7"  "E8"  "E9"  "E10" "E11" "F1" 
[61] "F2"  "F3"  "F4"  "F5"  "F6"  "F7"  "F8"  "F9"  "F10" "F11" "F12" "G1"  "G2"  "G3"  "G4"  "G5"  "G6"  "G7"  "G8"  "G9" 
[81] "G10" "G11" "G12" "H1"  "H2"  "H3"  "H4"  "H5"  "H6"  "H7"  "H8"  "H9"  "H10" "H11" "H12"

$p16_cisplatin.txt
[1] "A1"  "A2"  "A3"  "A4"  "A5"  "A6"  "A7"  "A8"  "A9"  "A10" "A11" "A12" "B1"  "B2"  "B3"  "B4"  "B5"  "B6"  "B7"  "B8" 
[21] "B9"  "B10" "B11" "B12" "C1"  "C2"  "C3"  "C4"  "C5"  "C6"  "C7"  "C8"  "C9"  "C10" "C11" "C12" "D1"  "D2"  "D3"  "D4" 
[41] "D5"  "D6"  "D7"  "D8"  "D9"  "D10" "D11" "D12" "E1"  "E2"  "E3"  "E4"  "E5"  "E6"  "E7"  "E8"  "E9"  "E10" "E11" "E12"
[61] "F1"  "F2"  "F3"  "F4"  "F5"  "F6"  "F7"  "F9"  "F10" "F11" "F12" "G1"  "G2"  "G3"  "G4"  "G5"  "G6"  "G7"  "G8"  "G9" 
[81] "G10" "G11" "G12" "H1"  "H2"  "H3"  "H4"  "H5"  "H6"  "H7"  "H8"  "H9"  "H10" "H11" "H12"

$p18_cisplatin_b.txt
[1] "A7"  "A8"  "A9"  "A10" "A11" "A12" "B1"  "B2"  "B3"  "B4"  "B5"  "B6"  "B7"  "B8"  "B9"  "B10" "B11" "B12" "C1"  "C2"  
[21] "C3"  "C4"  "C5"  "C6"  "C7"  "C8"  "C9"  "C10" "C11" "C12" "D1"  "D2"  "D3"  "D4"  "D5"  "D6"  "D7"  "D8"  "D9"  "D10"
[41] "D11" "D12" "E1"  "E2"  "E3"  "E4"  "E5"  "E6"  "E7"  "E8"  "E9"  "E10" "E11" "E12" "F1"  "F2"  "F3"  "F4"  "F5"  "F6" 
[61] "F7"  "F8"  "F9"  "F10" "F11" "F12" "G1"  "G2"  "G3"  "G4"  "G5"  "G6"  "G7"  "G8"  "G9"  "G10" "G11" "G12" "H1"  "H2" 
[81] "H3"  "H4"  "H5"  "H6"  "H7"  "H8"  "H9"  "H10" "H11" "H12"

$p18_cisplatin.txt
[1] "A1" "A2" "A3" "A4" "A5"
```

Instead of seeing the elements that each of those data frames above have because they are different from the master list, I want to see which elements the data frames do NOT have when they are compared to the master list. As a short example, the first data frame that's different, $p01_control.txt should show "A4" because that's what it is missing. (I only know that it's missing "A4" because I went through the list and found which one was missing).

Please let me know how I can make the problem more clear if it's confusing. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use setdiff. you can try something like this:

```
lapply(rowcol.list,function(x) setdiff(masterlist[[1]],x))
```